# HTTP request wrapper (method, headers, parameters) for HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

Spoiled by Python (e.g. `requests.post(url, data={'p1':'v1','p2':'v2'}, headers={'H1': 'V1'})`), I am looking for an equivalent to use on Android.

My code is already run on separate Threads, so I don't need AsyncWhatever.

*HttpURLConnection* is recommended for Android because it is all kinds of lightweight, but the equivalent of the Python request is... large.

I see multiple partial (e.g. pre-encoded params string) solutions, and several problems to work around. Rather than risk mistakes or overlooking something writing it myself, I ask:
Is such a wrapper available already, a `request(Method, String, Map<String,String>, Map<String,String>)`, or similar?

I expect such a solution to need little code per call, and manage all weirdness (e.g. pre-Froyo keepAlive hack) itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I have the right solution for you. Had the same problem (spoiled by Node.js [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)) and didn't like the "interface" of `HttpURLConnection`.

You can find a tiny library without dependencies which wrappes `HttpURLConnection` in a way that not so common use cases can be implemented by using the wrapped HUC. It's called **[DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/)**. There is also a link to [alternative libraries](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background) in case you miss something.

A typical POST request with JSON payload and JSON response with some headers would look like this:

```java
JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject();
postObj.put("p1", "v1");
postObj.put("p2", "v2");

Webb webb = Webb.create();
Response<JSONObject> response = webb
        .post("http://www.example.com/app/myresource")
        .header("x-date-header", new Date())
        .header("x-other-header", "some-text")
        .body(postObj)
        .connectTimeout(3000)
        .asJsonObject();

if (response.isSuccess()) {
    JSONObject outcome = response.getBody();

    // ...

} else {
    System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
    System.out.println(response.getResponseMessage());
    System.out.println(response.getErrorBody());
}
```

There are many ways to set default values for the `Webb` instance and use or overwrite them in the `Request` object.

The library is well tested, especially on Android, but it has no specific code or dependencies on Android API, so you have to manage `keepAlive` for Froyo by yourself.